# How to verify that an internal method is called in unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I do unit testing generally by verifying the state of my object after a method was run, but in some cases i need to test the behavior, not the final state.

For example, i need to add some code that will slow down a method that executes too fast.

I know we can test behavior by mocking objects, but generally we don't mock the object under test, only the collaborators.

So how can I verify in my unit test that myObject.MyMethod is calling for example 10 times myObject.WaitFor15ms ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that you need to test `MyObject` type.

In order to test its internal or protected methods you can create `MyObjectForTesting` type, override methods or inject some logic that can help you to test `MyObject`.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSmth_InvokesWaitFor15Minutes()
    {
        //arrange
        var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        var target = new MyObjectForTesting();

        // act
        target.DoSmth(list);

        // assert
        target.WaitFor15MinutesCounter.Should().Be(list.Length);
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public void DoSmth(int[] list)
        {
            list.ForEach(it => WaitFor15Minutes());
        }

        protected virtual void WaitFor15Minutes()
        {
        }
    }

    public class MyObjectForTesting : MyObject
    {
        public int WaitFor15MinutesCounter { get; private set; }

        protected override void WaitFor15Minutes()
        {
            WaitFor15MinutesCounter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes in fact that is exactly what I did for this case, but I was wondering if there were something available with a mock tool that can achieve this without manually coding a derived class each time, because it may be more complex than a simple counter.